# Count siempre devuelve 1

Tags: php

Tengo un form en el que paso por post el usuario y password.
Hago un count para verificar que exista el usuario, el problema es que siempre me devuelve 1.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" role="form" id="login-form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acc" class="sr-only">Cuenta</label>
        <input type="text" name="acc" id="acc" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pass" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <span class="character-checkbox" onclick="showPassword()"></span>
        <span class="label">Mostrar contraseña</span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Ingresar">   
</form>
```

class_users.php

```
<?php
require('db.php');
class Usuario {
    function checkUser($acc, $pass){
        require('db.php');
        $data = array($acc, md5($pass));
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM usuarios where desc_usuario = ? and password = ? ");

        $result = $stmt->execute($data);

        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('actions/db.php');
include('actions/users/class_users.php');
$acc = $_POST['acc'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$usr = new Usuario();
$user = $usr->checkUser($acc, $pass);
echo $user;
```

Comment: Te recomiendo no usar md5 para encriptar tus claves no es seguro.

Answer (score 2):

Estás capturando el valor de la ejecución

```
$result = $stmt->execute($data);
return $result;
```

En este caso, la respuesta  `1` sólo indica que el statement se ejecutó.
Tienes que traerte los registros obtenidos a partir de esa ejecución. Por ejemplo

```
$resultados = $stmt->fetchAll();
$validos = count($resultados);
return $validos;
```

Answer (score -1):

Se podría hacer de está manera teniendo los datos de:

```
$acc = $_POST['acc'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
```

Primero es necesario consultar si existe el usuario en la BBDD para luego verificar si la contraseña coincide con la que está en la BBDD.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE desc_usuario='$acc'"); //Consulta en la BBDD la existencia del usuario

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { //Verifica si el usuario existe
    $pass_db = $row["password"]; //Obtener el pass de la BBDD
    if (password_verify($pass, $pass_db)) {
        echo "Identificado correctamente";
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo guardar los passwords en HASH y no en Md5

Para guardar el password en un registro:

```
$pass = password_hash(base64_encode(hash('sha384', $input_pass, true)), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Y para consultar en un login.

```
$pass = base64_encode(hash('sha384', $input_pass, true));
```

Comment: La recomendación de hash por md5 está bien, pero antes pones un código que es inseguro y vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Puedes editar el código para todos podamos tomar en cuenta tus observaciones.